# How to secure a single file download over HTTP on IIS?

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, authentication

I want to create a download link to a file on my HTTP server (IIS 7.5), for a one time secure download purpose. I don't want the file to be publicly available, the receiver must authenticate.

When user visits the link:

`https://www.mydomain.com/download/receiver/file.zip`

I want the auth prompt to popup, if the user authenticates, then download should start.

I don't want to create a Windows user account for every file/receiver, that is, as I understand, required for Basic authentication to work. Creating IIS User is acceptable. But I can't seem to find a way to enable IIS Manager Authentication for a certain file or folder, web application, or even a completely new dedicated website.

(FTP is not an option for several reasons.)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/09/26/using-iis-manager-users-in-your-application.aspx ?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Thank you, theoretically that should do it. Please post the content as an answer for those that are also interested. I must say this is a very complex way to do it. Personally I don't think I'm prepared to perform all these steps for every secure download I want to serve. Lets hope there is a more clean way...

Answer (score 2):

This describes a way to do what you ask, although it requires manually editing web.config and changing security permissions on it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/09/26/using-iis-manager-users-in-your-application.aspx

You might also consider http://www.helicontech.com/ape/ which enables the Apache .htpasswd style authentication, but it isn't free.

What is your objection to creating Windows accounts for this? Perhaps there's a way around your concerns with that, as it would be an easy way to accomplish what you want without adding extras into IIS.

Answer (score -1):

Consider if instead of username and password authentication you can use some long "secret" URL. 
https://www.example.com/download/receiver/djd343dw3k6k3mnb3b5j6nn2b3/file.zip
You can send this URL to that person eg. by email or WhatsApp and no one else will ever know this exist. 
This works with any web server (IIS/nginx/Apache) and any client browser.
No need to create the user name.
Inspect or monitor your web server log file when this file was accessed and then delete it. 
hope this helps others searching for this question, even if your question is some what old.

Comment: It was explicitly required in the question that an user MUST authenticate. Therefore, this doesn't answer the question at all. Also, "super secret URLs" are easier to leak than separated URL, username and password.